# OSX and OpenGL : ERROR: Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I have an OpenGL project I'm attempting to run in OSX 10.8, so far the project compiles correctly and when you attempt to start it, XQuartz will come up. However, before anything appears on the screen, the following error comes up.

```
ERROR:  Internal error <FBConfig with necessary capabilities not found> in function fgOpenWindow
```

I've never seen this error before and Googling it hasn't provided any answers. I'm wondering if anyone has come across it before and knows how to get rid of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your program uses X11 to create windows and attempts to create an OpenGL context through that. However the X11 server shipping with OS X is rather limited and has only limited support for OpenGL.

You should change your program in a way that on OS X it creates Windows natively uses the system's OpenGL Framework instead of trying to use X11 on OS X.